# Python list comprehension: is there a way to do [func(x) for x in list1 or list2]

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Or  [func(x) for x in list1 and list2] (for some function `func`), without having to create a new list that happens to be the union or intersection of the two lists.

Comment: You're using a list comprehension so you're going to end up with a new list. If you just want the union of the two lists, you can just do `list1.extend(list2)`. This will modify `list1` without creating a new list.

Comment: I guess I simplified the example too much. My bad, I edited to fix that. I'm doing something with x (let's say pairing it up with another value). so it is not just that I am creating a new list that happens to be  union/intersection of list1 and list2.

Comment: @beetea: this might create duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to join the two lists without creating a new one:

```
from itertools import chain
lst = [x for x in chain(list1, list2)]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> [x for x in chain(list1, list2)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(chain(list1, list2))  # Equivalent
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

[x for x in itertools.chain(list1,list2)]
```

Note that this will add duplicates, so it's neither a union nor an intersection. If you want a true union/intersection:

```
set.union(map(set, [list1,list2])) # cast to list if you need
# union
set.intersection(map(set, [list1,list2])) # cast to list if you need
# intersection
```

From your edit:

```
def func(x):
    pass
    # do something useful

for element in list1:
    if element in list2:
        func(element)
# Or, but less readably imo
# # for element in filter(lambda x: x in list2, list1):
# #     func(element)
```

Comment: Both of these ways create new lists/sets. Right? It is not just checking if x is in list1 or list2. It is creating a third list and iterating over it.

Comment: If that's all you want, try `filter(lambda x: x in list2, list1)`

Comment: of course this can be done in a for-loop (and actually only the intersection is straightforward. union is tricky). My question is whether Python's list comprehension offers a way to do this, without needing to create a new data structure. Python list comprehension seems quite powerful, but I haven't been able to do this task in it.

Comment: @AnasElghafari `[func(x) for x in set.union(map(set, [list1,list2]))]` is the best you'll get for a union. For an intersection you can do `[func(x) for x in list1 if x in list2]`

Answer (score 1):

You want [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
[... in itertools.chain(list1, list2)]
```